# Next.js advanced client-side routing

Tags: next.js, url-routing, react-context

In a Next.js app (full-featured, **not** `next export`) that uses React Context for state management and the file-system based router, how can you implement advanced routing?

I want to have preconditions for certain pages, so for instance if you try to load `/foo` but the Context doesn't have a given property set correctly, it'll route you to `/bar`.

The actual logic is complex and varies by page, so I'm looking for an approach that's easy to maintain.

Note that these preconditions are **not** authorization-related, so they do not need to be enforced server-side. It's more like "you need to fill out this form before you can go here."

The use of Context imposes some constraints:

- Context must be accessed in a React component or in a custom Hook
- Using a custom server for routing is not an option, as that would lose the Context - it has to use client-side routing
- The *current* Context has to be checked (I tried decorating `useRouter`, but if the Context was changed right before `router.push`, the custom Hook saw the old values)

**Update**: It's also good to avoid a flash when the page loads before rerouting happens, so a side goal is to return a loading indicator component in that case.

Comment: This sounds like standard dynamic routing or even maybe catch all routing should work.  Have you tired either of them?  They can both be done client-side and both would have access to your context.   When you build your site you could even do the logic before hand in staticProps and update whenever the logic updates with ISR or just check on every request.  You have a few options. https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: @SeanW We're already doing both dynamic routes and catch all routes. Think of this more as page preconditions based on client-side state (frequently applicable to multiple pages) than typical routing concerns.

Comment: A custom HOC wrapped in the Next.js withRouter HOC is probably the simplest solution - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#withrouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can create a HOC and wrapped every pages with you HOC that takes arguments e.g. { redirects: '/foo' }

```
// pages/bar.tsx
const Page = () => {...}

export default RouteHOC({ redirects: '/foo' })(Page)
```

the HOC file will be something like this

```
// hoc/RouteHOC.tsx
const RouteHOC = ({ redirects }) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  
  // you can do your logic here with the context.. even filling up a form here 
  // too also can.. (like returning a modal first before the real Component). 
  // useEffect work here too..
  
  const { replace } = useRouter()
  
  // then after you want to replace the url with other page
  replace(redirects)
  
  return WrappedComponent
}
```

This is pretty okay to be maintainable I think. You just create all the logic in HOC and when you want to update the logic - you just have to edit it in 1 file.

Well this is one option I can think of when reading your question - sorry if I misunderstood it in any way. There will always be a better way out there as we all know we can improve and adapt to new situation every seconds :D. Cheers !!

Comment: This does appear to work based on some prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
const Component = () => {
  const example = useExample()

  return <div id='routes'>
    <a href='/example1'>Example 1</a>
    {example.whatever && <a href='/example2'>Example 1</a>}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Good to know, but server-side I wouldn't have access to Context, so I would have no way to check the Context-dependent preconditions.

Comment: I'm not sure what portion of the statement is incorrect. You can't access Context server-side. I need to query Context in order to route correctly. Therefore, I need to do routing client-side.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried a similar technique, adding a decorator to `useRouter`. When a `setSomeContext` executed right before `router.push`, the Context updates appeared to happen after the push function ran (apparently updates are async). So the check would fail on the first try but succeed on the second.